# Could not cast value of type __NSCFDictionary to NSData only when app is not fresh installed

Tags: swift, nsdata

When this code runs on a fresh app install, it works perfectly fine. However, when there is no data previously saved on the device, this function causes the app to crash.

I get the error `Could not cast value of type __NSCFDictionary to NSData` and it returns a thread zero error on the following line:

`playlists = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(playlistsData as! Data) as! [String:[Song]]`

Here is my full function code below:

```
func getPlaylists() -> [String:[Song]] {
        var playlists: [String:[Song]] = [:]
        let playlistsData = defaults.object(forKey: "user_playlists")
        if playlistsData != nil {
            playlists = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(playlistsData as! Data) as! [String:[Song]]
        }

        return playlists
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data safely change the method to

```
func getPlaylists() -> [String:[Song]] {
    guard let playlistsData = defaults.data(forKey: "user_playlists"),
          let playlists = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(playlistsData) as? [String:[Song]] else { return [:] }
    return playlists
}
```

By the way the error occurs because you previously saved a dictionary to `UserDefaults` rather than `Data`.

You probably mean *However, when there **is** data previously saved*...

Comment: Will this fix still require me to reinstall the app so that the old user default that was saved as a dictionary no longer exist?

Comment: Yes, but you could conditionally read UserDefaults, please edit the question and add the code to save the dictionary.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I beg your pardon? My answer avoids the crash.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand the problem greatly!

Answer (score 0):

First time works as `playlistsData` is nil in the beginning

```
 let playlistsData = defaults.object(forKey: "user_playlists")

  >>>>>>   hereis the crash  >>>>> playlistsData as! Data
```

you should store the object in `Data` not as a `Dictionary`  with

```
guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: somethingToSave, requiringSecureCoding: false) else { return }
defaults.set(data,forKey:"user_playlists")
```